# Terminal error in VS Code when starting the Python Debugger

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

On Ubuntu 20.04 with the VS Code (Version: 1.59.1) interpreter set to Python 3.8.5 and the python extension installed I receive the following error from the terminal when starting the debugger:

*The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "bin/sh" does not exist.*

I can successfully debug using for example ipdb by adding breakpoint() to a python file and executing it, but not through the VS Code debugger itself. When working with C# projects and files I can, though, use the VS Code debugger without a hitch, i.e., set breakpoints in the gutter and run with F5.

Comment: What is the first line of your Python script?

Comment: @wovano # src/data_sync/opgaver.py

Comment: Also, look in your VSCode settings for the setting `terminal.integrated.shell.linux`. This may be incorrect.

Comment: Were there more lines detailing the fail? Somewhere you got a shell script or configuration looking for `bin/sh` (relative path) instead of `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Thanks @wovano. Terminal.integrated.shell.linux was set to bin/sh. Changing this to /bin/sh did not work, but setting it to nothing and then setting the linux integrated default profile to bash worked. Does this make sense to the two of you?

Comment: @tdelaney, thanks for your help. Modifying the integrated terminal settings worked. See my comment above to wovano.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why `/bin/sh` doesn't work (if it exists on your system). But maybe VSCode is programmed to work with bash only (bash is not the same as sh). Anyway, that's a different question. I'm glad this one is solved for you.